# I want to convert a email address to xxx.xxx@gmail.com in php

Tags: php

I have dynamically generated email id

say `testing1234.gjj@gmail.com` .
I want to convert email id to `xxxxxxxxxx.xxx@gmail.com` .

Please tell me how can i implement this in php  for any email address .

Answer (score 4):

Try with following simple way, by using explode() function you will get email domain and you can easily append that domain to new email address as follow.

```
<?php
    $strEmail = "testing1234.gjj@gmail.com";

    $arrEamil = explode("@", $strEmail);
    $arrReverse = array_reverse($arrEamil);
    $strEamilDomain = $arrReverse[0];

    if ($strEamilDomain != "") {
        $strNewEmail = "xxxxxxxxxx.xxx@".$strEamilDomain;
    }
    echo $strNewEmail;
?>
```

Comment: If you think it helpful for you please take a step to accept it

Comment: Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this one (if you want to replace all letters by 'x')

```
$myMail      = 'testing1234.gfhhfdhg@gmail.com';
$myMailArray = str_split($myMail);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($myMailArray); $i++) {
    switch ($myMailArray[$i]) {
    case '@':
        break 2;
    case '.':
        break;
    default:
        $myMailArray[$i] = 'x';
    }
}
$mailAnon = implode($myMailArray);
echo $mailAnon;
```

Comment: But i want it something like this anugrah.agarwal@gmail.com
a***r***a***w**@gmail.com.Can you please share the logic for the same

Comment: What's the generic algorithm behind converting anugrah.agarwal@gmail.com to ara***w**@gmail.com? Which letters should be replaced by *?